# Error: You need to define CIVICRM_DSN in civicrm.settings.php civicrm 5.46.0 on Wordpress

Tags: installation

I am quite new to civicrm, but managed to get a site up and running (the instance had records etc)- somehow I managed to delete the uploads folder. so I did a fresh install of Wordpress 5.9, created a new database for civicrm and a fresh install of civicrm 5.46.0.  I enter database details, installation starts, but stops with this error, you need to define CIVICRM_DSN in civicrm.settings.php, but the file doesn't exist neither does the civicrm folder in uploads.  I have chmod plugins and uploads with write permissions, tried creating the folder myself, I don't know what else to do to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

The civicrm.settings.php by default is in:
/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php

So if you deleted the uploads folder it might make sense it can not find it.

The civicrm folder in uploads contains a lot more as well.

You mentioned you did a fresh install of civicrm, that actually should have created this folder, with everything in it. So my guess is that went wrong. So, you might want to retry that.

Comment: Yes after deleting the uploads folder - I deleted everything and did a fresh install of Wordpress (with a new uploads folder) and a new install of civicrm, but it won't write to the new uploads folder.  I am going to delete it all and try again.